# How to find a list of most influential or cited papers in a given branch of math?

Tags: mathematics

INSPIRE has a [list](http://inspirehep.net/info/hep/stats/topcites/2015/eprints/to_math_annual.html) of the 100 most highly cited papers during 2015 in the math archive as well as the [one](http://inspirehep.net/info/hep/stats/topcites/2015/eprints/by_hep-th_annual.html) for hep-th. The one for math is probably a bit skewed toward physics, since this "archive" probably means that of INSPIRE, which is known for physics rather than math. Either way, what I'm interested to see are similar lists for each mathematical branch (e.g. math-ag) rather than math as a whole. I've found an old list for math-ph only, but it seems that that's all from INSPIRE. I suppose this sort of data is useful for the situation of the following kind. Let's say my area of interest is far from probability, yet I'm interested in a list of the recent hot papers in probability for fun. Mathoverflow may be useful for learning about hot papers, but it's time-consuming for my purpose, since I want a rather extensive list for each of many branches of math. Elsevier's journal such as Advanes in Mathematics have most downloaded/cited lists, but this is just for each journal of Elsevier only, which is quite limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are after highly cited work, [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/) has such a functionality under the tab  [Citations](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/citations.html):

[image: screenshot of MathSciNet]

You can search highly cited work e.g. by subject or by year but note that citations come in slowly into MathSciNet, so data from a year ago may not say too much yet.